# Is Phone Gap still a viable option for building a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I've got a web app that I've built in php with laravel and the client wants an app in the apple and android app stores.

The app would need to have 2 functions.

1. An audio player for a streaming station. The station is an icecast stream that runs 24/7.
2. A way to pull in news from the website via a json api and display the associated images, titles and body on a rotator or something.

Is PhoneGap still viable for this? It doesn't look to be too actively developed on a quick glance.

Thanks

Comment: Completely doable in PhoneGap/Cordova

Comment: "Quick and cheap" are subjective concepts, they depend on many factors as the developer skill and experience, the level of support you need to give after deploying the app, which devices you need to support, etc... I think this question is not a good fit for SO as it is broad and opinion based. I can however agree with @JohnSmith in saying that definitely possible to implement those requirements in an hybrid app.

Comment: Edited to remove the subjective concepts. I really want to utilize SO for learning but everytime I ask a question it gets crapped on immediately. I guess I need to find another site.

Comment: I'm not saying that your question is not interesting, it is actually a clever question, but the rule of this site are that question must ask a "specific programming question" (see here http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), not an opinion on whether a library or a technology is good or not. This said, I can give you my opinion: the answer is yes, go for it, but if you are to maintain the application after deploying it expect further work. Apple and Google periodically make changes to WebView components that potentially will break your app.

Comment: And yes, maybe other sites could be more appropriate for this broad kind of questions, for example www.quora.com? (I'm not affiliated with it in any way)

Comment: I feel like my question is specific. Can X do Y and Z. I do get your point though and appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking as a full-time Cordova/PhoneGap developer: yes, totally doable in Cordova/PhoneGap, and both flavors of the framework (Cordova and PhoneGap) are being actively developed with new releases appearing regularly. The latest Cordova iOS release was last week, the latest Android was two weeks ago. You can find release info and active support here: https://cordova.apache.org/